# How to show user dialog box after recyclerview item click

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, edit

I have an image button in my  recylerview and when users click it, I want a dialog box to pop up and allow the user to edit the data in the reyclerview and save the changes.

[image]

**My Adapter code**

```
class Adapter(private var records: ArrayList<AudioRecord>, var listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

private var editMode = false

fun isEditMode() :Boolean{return editMode}
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
fun setEditMode(mode: Boolean){
    if(editMode != mode){
        editMode = mode
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemviewLayoutBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root ), View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{
    private var tvFileName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFilename)
    private var tvMeta : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMeta)
    var checkbox : CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)
    val editBtn: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit)



    init {

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this)
    }

    fun binding (audioRecord: AudioRecord) {

        tvFileName.text = audioRecord.filename
        tvMeta.text = audioRecord.duration

        // checkbox.text = audioRecord.

    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        val position = adapterPosition
        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
            listener.onItemClickListener(position)
    }

    override fun onLongClick(p0: View?): Boolean {
        val position = adapterPosition
        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
            listener.onItemLongClickListener(position)

        return true
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(ItemviewLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))

}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "SimpleDateFormat")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){

        val record: AudioRecord = records[position]
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        val date = Date(record.timestamp)
        val strDate = sdf.format(date)

        holder.binding.tvFilename.text = record.filename
        holder.binding.tvMeta.text = "${record.duration} $strDate"

        if(editMode){
            holder.checkbox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.checkbox.isChecked = record.isChecked
            holder.editBtn.visibility = View.GONE
        }else{
            holder.checkbox.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.checkbox.isChecked = false
            holder.editBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }

        holder.binding.btnEdit.setOnClickListener {
            
        }
    }
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return records.size
}
```

}

**Summary**

1. When users click image button. Input dialog pops up
2. User must be able to edit data in recyclerview and save it.

Answer (score 0):

change class like this `inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemviewLayoutBinding), var imageListener:(position:Int)->Unit)`

where you call adapter , use `imageListener` function. Whatever you want to do you can do it inside this function. Then call it in your adapter.

in `init`

```
editBtn.setOnClickListener {
  imageListener(adapterPosition)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting No value passed for parameter 'imageListener'